# Auth0 and react, redirect user to signup page

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I am using `Auth0` for my authentication on a React + C# asp.net core page.

I would like the users to click "Sign up" and it direct them to the Auth0 Universal Sign up page. I'm able to direct users to the Login Page with this code:

```
await loginWithRedirect({
    appState: { targetUrl: location.pathname || window.location.pathname },
});
```

Using the example react-auth0-spa.js and @auth0/auth0-spa-js library.

However, I can't see any examples online on how to direct a user directly to the sign up (not login) page.

Comment: do u use react-router?

Comment: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11/configuration?_ga=2.151751935.776359461.1583073018-105845438.1583073018#initialscreen-string- ?

Comment: the auth0 lock might work, i was using hte universal login page.. but i could change

Comment: yes i do use react-router, my only problem is determining the URL and the "state" query string that auth0 requires.

Comment: have you seen @MoshFeu link? also consider these [1] https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#signup and [2]https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/custom-signup

Comment: Dear @michael, please explain a little more or upload a re-production sample of your issue on GitHub, GitLab or CodeSandBox, I will try to settle your issue.

Comment: Why do you want to redirect a user to sign up? Then each time a user needs to login after first sign up they will be redirected to the sign up page?

Comment: Where is your code??

Comment: michael so you basically want the users to be redirected to a specific link when they click a "Sign up" button?

Comment: @Michael could you try to use the login_hint parameter to pass the value `signUp`? That's what I provide in one of my applications to make it go directly to the signUp page. In your case: `await loginWithRedirect({ login_hint: 'signUp', targetUrl: ... })`. Documentation: https://auth0.github.io/auth0-spa-js/interfaces/redirectloginoptions.html

Answer (score 1):

The two prior answers refer to v1 and v2 of our SDKs respectively. We introduced new parameters as `authorizationParams` in [v2 in 2022](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js/tree/v2.0.0) in order to structure these better and allow room for improvements like your own custom parameters. This breaking change is documented in our version [migration guide](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js/blob/master/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md#introduction-of-authorizationparams).

Expanding a bit on the other answers, from the v2 docs:

```
await client.loginWithRedirect({
  appState: {
    key: value // state to restore when getting redirected back
  },
  authorizationParams: {
    screen_hint: 'signup',
    any_custom_property: 'value'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but I just had the exact same problem myself using the `auth0-spa-js` client so hopefully someone else will stumble on this answer and find it useful.

The solution was to pass the `screen_hint` param to the `loginWithRedirect` method like this:

```
loginWithRedirect({screen_hint: 'signup'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they've changed it again (as of 07/05/2023). To navigate directly to the Sign Up portion of the login you need to use the authorizationParams.

```
loginWithRedirect({
  authorizationParams: {
     'screen_hint': 'signup',
  }});
```

Credits to [this article](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-pass-authorizationparams-to-loginwithredirect-to-direct-users-to-auth0-sign-up).